# INSERT more than one row in table on button click

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-ce

This code works fine but its INSERTING values only from textbox1 textbox2 and Date2 what if i have more textboxes and labels how to INSERT multiple rows from different controls  in one click.

To be precise i have 10 pair textboxes  textbox 1 and textbox 2 then textbox3 and textbox 4 and 10 Labels 
Date 2 / 4 /6 / 8

So on each row i want values from textbox[i] textbox[i+1] Date[i+1] and global varialbe buyEUR

```
private void InsertData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\FluksikartoN\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BuroFoki\BuroFoki\MainDB.sdf");
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO TenOperations (EUR, Rate, BGN, Date) Values(@EUR, @Rate, @BGN, @Date)", connection))
    {
       /* for (int i = 2; i <= 20; i = i+2)
       {
          TextBox txtBox1 = this.Controls["TextBox" + (i - 1).ToString()] as TextBox;
          TextBox txtBox2 = this.Controls["TextBox" + i.ToString()] as TextBox;
          Label Date = this.Controls["Date" + i.ToString()] as Label;*/
          com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EUR", textBox2.Text.ToString());
          com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", EURbuy);
          com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BGN", textBox1.Text.ToString());
          com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date2.Text.ToString());
          /*
          com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EUR", textBox4.Text.ToString());
          com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", EURbuy);
          com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BGN", textBox3.Text.ToString());
          com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date4.Text.ToString());
          */
          com.ExecuteNonQuery();

       }

       connection.Close();

     }
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but maybe you should add your parameters only once, before the loop (com.Parameters.Add("@EUR", [ParamType])), and then, inside the loop, just set the value for the parameter (com.Parameters["@EUR"].Value = textBox4.Text.ToString()) and execute the query.

Comment: can you shot an example im not sure if ExecuteNonQuery has to be inside the loop or not just please show me example to get the idea better

Comment: Why you cannot use `DataGridView` or `DataGrid` controls. With htat controls you can rid of multiply textboxes and lables

Comment: have already started with textboxes and labels.Styling them is better than DataGrid/View. Dont have much experience with DataGrid but I tried and couldnt remove some things I dont wan't in the Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a control array [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (although there is no inherent support you can duplicate the functionality) then you can get the values to add as parameters using a loop and insert the value in database.

Comment: but after i have created all needed controls how do i apply more than one row   in my example even if i remove   `/**/`   which surround   `com.Parameters.AddWithValue`
  
it give me an error

Comment: your Insert statement has 4 parameters, if you remove remove /**/  then you are adding same parameter more than once, So you will get the error. you need to keep the insert statement inside the loop and then add the parameters(from the control array) within the loop.

Comment: so the `loop` must begin after `connection.open()` and finish before `connection.close()`

Comment: Yes.After closing connection you can not insert values.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works.

```
using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO TenOperations (EUR, Rate, BGN, Date) Values(@EUR1, @Rate1, @BGN1, @Date1),(@EUR2, @Rate2, @BGN2, @Date2)", connection))
     {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EUR1", textBox2.Text.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate1", EURbuy);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BGN1", textBox1.Text.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", Date2.Text.ToString());

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EUR2", textBox4.Text.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate2", EURbuy);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BGN2", textBox3.Text.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2", Date4.Text.ToString());

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
```